# How to send pdf via gmail api

Tags: javascript, email, gmail, gmail-api

I have implemented gapi/ 0Auth2 elsewhere in my code and everything works, except the attached PDF is broken. The PDF can not be previewed and is empty when downloaded.

´´´

```
function stuffer() {
var sender = "sender@gmail.com";
var receiver = "reciver@hotmail.com";

let dem = pdfCon("ny brab verder");
console.log(dem);

var mail = [
  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\r\n',
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
  "From: " + sender + "\r\n",
  "To: " + receiver + "\r\n",
  "Subject: Subject Text\r\n\r\n",

  "--foo_bar_baz\r\n",
  'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"\r\n',
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n",

  "The actual message text goes here\r\n\r\n",

  "--foo_bar_baz\r\n",
  "Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n",
  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
  "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n",
  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="generated.pdf"\r\n\r\n',

  dem,
  "\r\n\r\n",

  "--foo_bar_baz--",
].join("");
return sendMessage(mail);

}

  function sendMessage(message) {
    var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(message)
      .replace(/\+/g, "-")
      .replace(/\//g, "_");
    gapi.client.gmail.users.messages
      .send({
        userId: "me",
        resource: {
          raw: base64EncodedEmail,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  function pdfCon(content) {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.text(content, 10, 10);
    pdf.setProperties({
      title: "new Report",
    });
    return pdf.output("datauristring");
  }
```

´´´

I have tried premade PDF, rather than jsPDF.

I have followed the documentation on google and looked at different post, but there seem to be no documentation for this specifik problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your script, I thought that the returned value from `pdfCon("ny brab verder")` is the data URL. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let dem = pdfCon("ny brab verder");
```

#### To:

```
let dem = pdfCon("ny brab verder").split(",")[1];
```

- In this modification, the header is removed from the data URL. By this, only the base64 data is retrieved.